# wp_nav_menu (secondary menu) not adding current classes

Tags: menus

I've looked everywhere, but i can't find a solution.

My secondary menu isn't adding any current classes to the

tags when it's rendered.

I have added this menu in my functions.php file

```
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'second-menu' => __( 'Second Menu' )
        )
    );
}
```

Then I created a menu in wordpress with the links I want to show in my Second Menu.
After that I've added the menu with the function wp_nav_menu in the .php file where I want the menu to show:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'second-menu' ) ); ?>
```

So far everything works. The menu is showing with the links I want it to show. All the links are working. My problem is, that the 'current' classes which WP normally adds to the menus aren't added to this menu. I've expected the classes current-menu-item or current-page-item to the

tag, but these aren't there. The only classes which WP adds to the

tag are:

- menu-item
- menu-item-type-post_type
- menu-item-object-page
- menu-item-[number]

Thanks for the help,
Angelo

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign the menu to the particular theme option from the admin end,

Orelse use this code,

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'second-menu' ) );
```

Instead of,

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'second-menu' ) );
```

This will work.

Comment: When I do this, the main-menu shows instead of the menu I want to show (second-menu). From the admin end, you mean url.com/wp-admin right? I created a menu there which includes the link I want to show.

Comment: @AngeloA.. Have you assigned the newly created menu to the "Second Menu" when you create the menu. Only then it will be showing up when you use the theme_location in it.

Comment: I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

These don't match:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'second-menu' => __( 'Second Menu' )
    )
);
```

and

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'producten-menu' ) )
```

Your `'theme_location'` must match the slug passed to the `register_nav_menus()` array:

```
register_nav_menus( array( $slug => $title ) );
```

gets called as:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => $slug ) );
```

So try:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'second-menu' ) );
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've changed it, but it's still not working :(

Comment: Please elaborate on "*it's still not working*". What are you expecting to happen, and what's actually happening?

Comment: The menu is showing, but the problem is that no current-classes are added to the menu. So I can't add use CSS to show the active (current) menu-item.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include what you've tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened (including the actual classes output, where you expect a "current" class to be output). Also, did you **assign a custom nav menu** to the Theme Location?